# Get custom references of project

Tags: c#, dll

I created a project (DLL) and added some references of other my projects, how I can get a list of this "custom" references?

I write this code, but not return my references.

```
    public List<string> getDependencies()
    {
        List<string> lDependencies = new List<string>();

        Assembly module = typeof(DummyModule).Assembly;
        foreach (AssemblyName an in module.GetReferencedAssemblies())
        {
             lDependencies.Add(an.Name);
        }

        return lDependencies;
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the right code!

My "DummyClass.cs"

```
public class DummyModule
{
    public List<string> getDependencies()
    {
        List<string> lDependencies = new List<string>();

        var assembly = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        var referencedAssemblies = assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies();

        foreach (var assemblyName in referencedAssemblies)
        {
            lDependencies.Add(assemblyName.Name);
        }

        if (lDependencies.Contains("mscorlib"))
            lDependencies.Remove("mscorlib");

        return lDependencies;
    }

    public void A()
    {
        Cryptography c = new Cryptography();
    }
 }
```

The constructor "Cryptography" is a class of Security.dll which I created and I added your reference to my actual project.

With the method "getDependencies" is possible to get all custom references added to the project, ONLY if you use the code of your reference (that is why I added the constructor "Cryptography").

Removing the "mscorlib" (default dll of NET Framework) you will get all references added to the project.

Simple, right? :)

Comment: *"The constructor "Cryptography" is a class of Security.dll which I created and I added your reference to my actual project."* this looks like you are talking to someone but there are no other comments in this question. Did you copy this text from somewhere else?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain No! I found the right code and I thought it is good to share with other people. I not copy this text from somewhere, is my answer =D